# cp: cannot stat './1_true/*': No such file or directory, when find directories and copy files

Tags: bash, find

i have many directories like this:

```
$ ls 
  1_true 1_false 2_true 2_false 3_true 3_false ...
```

i want to copy files in "*_true/" to other directory.

when i run command like below

```
find . -name "*_true" -exec cp "{}"/* "../out_true" ";"
```

this give me error messages like this:

```
cp: cannot stat './1_true/*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat './2_true/*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat './3_true/*': No such file or directory
...
```

how to fix this error? thanks!

NOTE: my 'true' directories count is more than 100000

Comment: Try `... -exec echo cp ...` to see what's happening

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it quite a bit

```
cp ?_true/* ../out_true/
```

will work as well.

This will, however, not work when you have [a very large number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755).

Comment: your code will work if my true directories count is less than 10. but my directories is more than 100000.

Comment: [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument)

Answer (score 1):

found answer, using `xargs` instead of `-exec`

```
find . -name "*_true" -print0 | xargs --null -I{} sh -c 'cp "$1"/* "../out_true"' -- {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit [find](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html) to descend not more than n levels with `-maxdepth`. This will match ***_true** and copy the content using [rsync](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/rsync.1.html). Trailing slash on the source directory will change the behavior of rsync and only copy the content of the directory and not the directory it self.

```bsh
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_true' -exec rsync -a "{}/" ../out_true \;
```

or

```bsh
for i in *_true; do
    rsync -a "$i/" ../out_true
done
```